# $f (x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 1 & x\geq 0, x\leq y\leq 1+x \\ -1 & x\geq 0, 1+x\leq y\leq 2+x \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{array} \right. $

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $f (x,y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1 & x\geq 0, x\leq y\leq 1+x \\
-1 &  x\geq 0, 1+x\leq y\leq 2+x \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right. $
Calculate $\int_\mathbb R\big (\int_\mathbb R f(x,y) dy\big)dx$ and $\int_\mathbb R\big (\int_\mathbb R f(x,y) dx\big)dy$\

I started with $\int_\mathbb R\big (\int_\mathbb R f(x,y) dy\big)dx$=$\int_0^\infty\big (\int_x^{1+x} 1 dy+\int_{1+x}^{2+x}-1dy\big)dx=0$

I don't know how to calculate the second integral because I don't know the integral limits

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. $x\geq 0, x\leq y\leq 1+x $ can be written as $1 \leq y<\infty, y-1\leq x \leq y$ or $0 \leq y \leq 1, 0\leq x \leq y$.
2. $ x\geq 0, 1+x\leq y\leq 2+x$ can be written as $ y-2 \leq x \leq y-1, 1 \leq y <\infty$.

Comment: if i plot the set $0\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq x\leq y$ it is a triangle, but $0\leq x, x\leq y\leq x+1$ is not a triangle

Comment: The figure splits into two parts  depending on whether $y<1$, or $y>1$ @Moritz

Comment: Draw  the  horizontal line  $y=1$. The region of integration will split into two parts (one of which is  a triangle). Now integrate over the two parts separately. [You can also evaluate the integral without the use of a picture as I have done in my answer. You will have to consider the case $y<1$ and $y>1$ separately because you cannot always write $\int_{y-1}^{y}$ dx due to the fact that $y-1$ may be negative and $x$ is not allowed to be negative.  @Moritz